# Keep navbar title in sync with displayed page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, apollo

I'm working on a Vue project, where I have a navbar component. On mobile, this component shows a title for the page. I need to set this title on a page by page basis, but haven't been able to find a reliable way to do it.

I've seen examples suggesting adding `meta: { title: 'My Page' }` to each of the routes for the app, then checking the matched route and applying the title. This doesn't work for me as on some pages the title will rely on data fetched from displayed page (e.g. `/posts/:id` would want the title to be the title of the post, which isn't available to the router).

Another option I considered is emitting an event, which sets the title. This would work, but would have to be reflected up multiple levels, and would require every page to have a title otherwise the previous title would remain after navigation.

Similar to the above, it could be implemented via Vuex to avoid having to pass the event up the chain, but would have the same issue of the previous title remaining after navigation. I could of course clear the value on route change, but this could introduce a race condition as the API request is cached, so revisiting a cached page could result in no title.

Ideally I want a mix between using `meta` values, and values dependent on the result of the API call. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you set `document.title = your_dynamic_title` whenever you fetch the dynamic content?

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/the-easy-way-to-change-page-title-in-vue-6caf05006863

Comment: The above isn’t reactive. It’s executed once immediately on component load, when any API data isn’t available. I’ve had a look online at ways of making it reactive but haven’t been able to find an answer - is there a way to make it behave like a computed value and update when a dependency changes value?

Comment: Would this work: `fetchTheData().then(newtitle => document.title = newtitle)`? Also you have to consider that the title would not change until you fetch the data, so on slow connections, it could display the old title for a while before changing it.

Comment: I found this online also, maybe it will help: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/914#issuecomment-326536513

Comment: Also check this module out: https://github.com/troxler/vue-headful

Comment: +1 for Vue Headful. Alternately would it be horrible to convert to Nuxt.js? That project has already modified Vue handle generated routes like a blog post from a headless CMS

Comment: I use [vuex-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta) with computed properties and it works great